# Tkinter - Transparent Labels?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a tkinter program that will count and display a number using a seven-segment font I have created. What I am wanting to achieve is when a segment is not being used, rather than it not displaying, I want it in a darker color. Example is for it to look like:

[image: 7seg example]

I created 2 fonts, 7seg (normal font) and 7seg inverted (unused segments showing in a darker colour) and wanted to overlay the 2 on top of each other with the bg on the top image being transparent. I tried using `wm_attributes` but that makes the whole thing transparen,t not just the top label. I am not sure if it's even possible...

The code regarding this part is:

```
segment_invert = Label(tab2, text = "888", font = ("7Seg_invert", 150), fg = "#800000",
                       bg = "black")
segment_invert.place(x = 20, y = 30)

segment = Label(tab2, text = "888", font = ("7 Segment none just", 150), fg = "red")
segment.place(x = 20, y = 30)
```

Basically I want the top `Label` to be see through and only show the none used segments revealing the used segments below.

This is how it currently looks:

[image: current image]

Comment: This *cannot* be done with Labels; like all Tkinter widgets, they're inherently opaque.  You might have better luck with two text objects on the same Canvas.

Comment: Because you can't do it the way you want as @jasonharper points out, and since there are only seven segments involved, just draw them in the desired color. You don't need a whole font, just a table for the 10 possible digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you, creating it as a canvas does exactly what i want

```
    import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk, Button, NORMAL, DISABLED, W, LabelFrame, Frame, Label, font, Canvas, Entry

main = tkinter.Tk()

std_size_w, std_size_h = "800","500"
main.geometry(f"{std_size_w}x{std_size_h}")
main.minsize(width = (int(std_size_w)), height = ((int(std_size_h))-300))


# Tabs
tab_setup = ttk.Notebook(main)

# Tab 1 Serial
tab1 = LabelFrame(tab_setup, text = "Setup Serial")
tab_setup.add(tab1, text = "Serial Setup")

tab2 = LabelFrame(tab_setup)
tab_setup.add(tab2, text = "Azkoyne Hopper U")

tab_setup.pack(expand=1, fill = "both", padx = 10, pady = 10)


canvas1 = Canvas(tab2, width = 400, height = 200, bg = "black") 
canvas1.pack()


canvas1.create_text(200, 100, text = "888", font = ("7 Segment none just", 150), fill = "#4d0000")
canvas1.create_text(200, 100, text = "000", font = ("7 Segment none just", 150), fill = "red")



main.mainloop()
```

screen shot here [working image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EtDh.png)

Comment: font is here https://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/1891146/7-segment-display-1-7